# How to delay something thats just a possibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm making a website, and i have a sort of a slider menu from top, and when i hover over a button everything appears, but when i hover out it doesn't disappear. In my js code i had to delay the disappearance with setTimeout() because there's a small gap between the button and the menu. So if someone would know how to make it disappear while keeping the timer thing so it doesn't disappear when going from button to the menu i'd be insanely grateful. Thanks in advance. Here's the code:

```js
var timeout;

function mouseOver(){
    document.getElementById('menu-roll').style.display = 'block';
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('menu-roll').style.display = 'none';}, 3000);
}

function mouseOut(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

```css
:root{
    --backg-primary: #ffeaa7;
    --backg-islands: #2d3436;
    --nav-wrapper: #4d0404;
    --nav-wrapper-hover: #F79F1F;
    --menu-roll: rgba(247, 159, 31, 0.95);
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#video-wrapper{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar{
    background-color: var(--nav-wrapper);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    transition: top 0.3s;
    top: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 7;
}
#navbar a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
#navbar a:hover{
    transition: background-color .25s ease, color .25s ease;
    background-color: var(--nav-wrapper-hover);
    color: var(--nav-wrapper);
}
#logo-wrapper{
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3.85px solid var(--nav-wrapper);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
    position: relative;
    animation: slideup 3s;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 45%;
}
@keyframes slideup{
    0%{
        top: 150px;
    }
    100%{
        top: 0;
    }
}
#menu-wrapper{
    width: 700px;
    height: 103px;
    background: var(--nav-wrapper);
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 8;
}
#logo-wrapper img{
    border-radius: 45%;
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
#video{
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
}
#menu-roll{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    background: var(--nav-wrapper-hover);
    width: 150px;
    top: 60px;
    padding: 15px;
    left: 2%;
    display: none;
}
#menu-roll #design-line-menu-roll{
    height: 4px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: var(--nav-wrapper);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#menu-roll a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    text-align: left;
    color: var(--nav-wrapper);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
#menu-roll a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
#h1-menu-tandoor{
    color: white;
    left: -100%;
    top: 12%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1.0;
    animation: textopacity 3.2s;
}
@keyframes textopacity{
    0%, 90%{
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
#h1-menu-restaurace{
    color: white;
    left: 110%;
    top: 14.5%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1.0;
    animation: textopacitytwo 3.2s;
}
@keyframes textopacitytwo{
    0%, 90%{
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
#information-section{
    background: var(--backg-primary);
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}
#introduction{
    padding-top: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 50px;
    background: #444;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
}
#introduction h1{
    font-size: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #edf3f8;
}
#introduction h3{
    font-size: 1.75em;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--nav-wrapper);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    color: var(--blend-in-text);
}
#introduction p{
    color: #edf3f8;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    padding: 15px 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#divider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: var(--nav-wrapper);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
}
#intro-photos{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 6;
    height: 10px;
}
.first-photo{
    width: 36.5%;
    height: auto;
    left: 62%;
    position: relative;
    top: -400px;
    z-index: 4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 218, 104);
    background: rgb(255, 218, 104);
}
#services-info{
    height: 407px;
}
#services-photo{
    top: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .first-photo{
        left: 12%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        top: 40px;
        width: 76.5%;
        padding-top: 15px;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    #introduction{
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #divider{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #services-info{
        height: 800px;
    }
    #services-photo{
        top: 470px;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="video-wrapper">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li id="menu-hover-roll" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
            <a href="#">Menu</a>
            <ul id="menu-roll">
                <div id="design-line-menu-roll"></div>
                <li><a href="#">Polední menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jídelní lístek</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nápoje</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <video id="video" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="styles/720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
        <div id="logo-wrapper">
            <div id="h1-menu-tandoor">
                <h1>Tandoor</h1>
            </div>     
            <div id="h1-menu-restaurace">
                <h1>Restaurace</h1>
            </div>
           <img src="styles/tndrlogo.jpg">
        </div>   
    </div>
    <div id="menu-roll">
        <div id="design-line-menu-roll"></div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Polední menu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Nápojový lístek</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you really want that EVERYTHING should appear not before the button is hovered, so that you have a white page except the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand everything but take a look at this code.

```js
var timeout;

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById('menu-roll').style.display = 'block';
  clearTimeout(timeout); 
}

function mouseOut() { 
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('menu-roll').style.display = 'none';
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --backg-primary: #ffeaa7;
  --backg-islands: #2d3436;
  --nav-wrapper: #4d0404;
  --nav-wrapper-hover: #F79F1F;
  --menu-roll: rgba(247, 159, 31, 0.95);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#video-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: var(--nav-wrapper);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  top: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 7;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  transition: background-color .25s ease, color .25s ease;
  background-color: var(--nav-wrapper-hover);
  color: var(--nav-wrapper);
}

#logo-wrapper {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3.85px solid var(--nav-wrapper);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
  position: relative;
  animation: slideup 3s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 45%;
}

@keyframes slideup {
  0% {
    top: 150px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}

#menu-wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  height: 103px;
  background: var(--nav-wrapper);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8;
}

#logo-wrapper img {
  border-radius: 45%;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

#video {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
}

#menu-roll {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  background: var(--nav-wrapper-hover);
  width: 150px;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 15px;
  left: 2%;
  display: none;
}

#menu-roll #design-line-menu-roll {
  height: 4px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: var(--nav-wrapper);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#menu-roll a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  text-align: left;
  color: var(--nav-wrapper);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

#menu-roll a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#h1-menu-tandoor {
  color: white;
  left: -100%;
  top: 12%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1.0;
  animation: textopacity 3.2s;
}

@keyframes textopacity {
  0%,
  90% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

#h1-menu-restaurace {
  color: white;
  left: 110%;
  top: 14.5%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1.0;
  animation: textopacitytwo 3.2s;
}

@keyframes textopacitytwo {
  0%,
  90% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

#information-section {
  background: var(--backg-primary);
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

#introduction {
  padding-top: 50px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #444;
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
}

#introduction h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #edf3f8;
}

#introduction h3 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--nav-wrapper);
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: var(--blend-in-text);
}

#introduction p {
  color: #edf3f8;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 15px 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: var(--nav-wrapper);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
}

#intro-photos {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
  height: 10px;
}

.first-photo {
  width: 36.5%;
  height: auto;
  left: 62%;
  position: relative;
  top: -400px;
  z-index: 4;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 218, 104);
  background: rgb(255, 218, 104);
}

#services-info {
  height: 407px;
}

#services-photo {
  top: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .first-photo {
    left: 12%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 40px;
    width: 76.5%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  #introduction {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #divider {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #services-info {
    height: 800px;
  }
  #services-photo {
    top: 470px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="styles/favicon.ico.png" />
  <title>Tandoor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="video-wrapper">
    <ul id="navbar">
      <li id="menu-hover-roll" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul id="menu-roll">
          <div id="design-line-menu-roll"></div>
          <li><a href="#">Polední menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jídelní lístek</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nápoje</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <video id="video" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="styles/720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
      <div id="logo-wrapper">
        <div id="h1-menu-tandoor">
          <h1>Tandoor</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="h1-menu-restaurace">
          <h1>Restaurace</h1>
        </div>
        <img src="styles/tndrlogo.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-roll">
      <div id="design-line-menu-roll"></div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Polední menu</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Nápojový lístek</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```